# Normal max entropy

Tags: self-study, bayesian, maximum-entropy

In the following link, at the bottom of the page.

https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Maximum_Entropy_Property_Gaussian.html

The Gaussian maximum entropy is derived.

I have a question about this,

Why are we allowed to simply use $\int_{\mathbb{R}}( x^{2}p(x) -\sigma^{2})dx$ for one of our constraints, given that $E[X]=\mu \lt \infty$

To me it seems, unless the mean was zero, that we would need

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}( (x-\mu)^{2}p(x) -\sigma^{2})dx$.

Which would give a different result when we differentiate with respect to $p(x)$ and solve for the Lagrange multipliers.

i.e in the first case we would get

$\lambda_{0}-1+\lambda_{1}x+\lambda_{2}x^{2}=\log(p(x))$

so $p(x)=\exp(\lambda_{0}-1+\lambda_{1}x+\lambda_{2}x^{2})$

while in the second we would get

$\lambda_{0}-1+\lambda_{1}x+\lambda_{2}(x^{2}-\mu)=\log(p(x))$

I also have some confusion about how many Lagrange multipliers we need.

For example, on the above page and example we have three, for three constraints, ie that it is a valid distribution, that it has finite mean and that it has finite variance (ie finite second moment combined with finite first moment).

But in *The Bayesian Choice* by Christian Roberts, we only have two Lagrange multipliers ( at least that seems to me).

Whereby the author writes it as proportional to $\exp(\theta \lambda_{1}+\theta^{2} \lambda_{2})$ , is one our $\lambda$ here just 1 and cancels out?

As I am trying to understand reference measures and such, and one example asks about having the standard normal as a maximum entropy prior. When it was Lebesgue measure with known mean and variance, we had it was proportional to $\exp(\lambda_{1} \theta+\lambda_{2} \theta^{2})$

If Lebesgue is just the most basic, then for another distribution h as a reference would we simply have the maximum entropy prior proportional (assuming exists).

to $\exp(\lambda_{1} \theta +\lambda_{2} \theta^{2}) h(\theta)$

As the author Christian Robert asks about reference measures that are absolutely continuous to one another, and from what I can gather this just means they have the same null set? But would that not be true for any continuous distribution? Since from what I can gather, Lebesgue is zero over points, non zero over intervals or such. Similar to continuous distributions which are zero at any given point.

Comment: You are correct in pointing out the mistakes on this webpage. The second constraint should see $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\sigma^2+\mu^2$ and (D.41) should not be the standard Normal.

Comment: You should break your question into several questions as the issues are rather disconnected.

Comment: @Xi'an . I made a new post where I tried to show what I understood. If you don't mind and have any time, would you possibly leave a suggestion or hint on that?